# Should you give write permissions for renaming your files in spool directory source in flume

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a flume agent which reads from a spool directory source and after some transformation writes to hdfs.
Since flume tries to rename the processed files to '.COMPLETED', I'am getting a permission denied exception for writing in the spool directory.

I was wondering how safe it would be to give write permission to sensitive data.

Is there a round about solution for flume to identify the processed files in the spool directory

Answer (score 0):

The spool directory source's way of working requires renaming of files.

As a workaround, it's safer to have a "read-only" copy of the files and create some mechanism (eg. cron job) that copies files to the spooling directory Flume has write access to. (And possibly set the `deletePolicy` configuration option to `immediate`, to avoid filling the disk.)

If you would like to request such a feature, I recommend creating a new ticket at https://issues.apache.org